# What's the shell command of importing a sql into a db . (MySQL, CentOS w/ cPanel)

Tags: mysql, shell, command

I have a big sql file (~ 60MB) exported from local development site, and I want to import to my server (running CentOS 5).

Lets say

- the dump file is **dump.sql**, uploaded to the server.
- the database name is **mydb**.

I want to do with via ssh, what is the shell command to do so?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can import (execute) an SQL file using the following command:

```
$ mysql -u user -p mydb < dump.sql
```

If you exported your data using some tool other than `mysqldump`, you may have troubles restoring your dump file. I ran into such a problem when I exported the database using phpmyadmin and imported it using the command line. To export your database, you can use:

```
$ mysqldump -u user -p mydb > dump.sql
```

For more options, you can see the help of each one of these tools.

Comment: thanks. is the command OS-dependent? I mean: if I dump mysql from my MacOS use the above mysqldump command, then import to my Linus server my the mysql.  Would this be fine?

Comment: It should work. The exported file is a text file. It is not binary. So, it should be OK. However, you have to confirm you got a text file with the correct encoding.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what was your compatibility problem with phpmyadmin? I've never had one but frequently export and import MySQL tables in that manner.

Comment: @Tim: I can't remember exactly, but either I could not import the file because of errors or I got corrupted text (encoding error).

Answer (score 1):

The other option is to do this from within the MySQL shell:

```
mysql> use mydb
mysql> source dump.sql
```